# Why does my ReactJS site crash Safari browsers?

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, macos, safari

My website "www.CarpeDiction.com" works fine when accessed from any browser other than Safari. When accessed through Safari, whether desktop or mobile, the homepage works alright, but upon making a query in the site's search box, the 'search' view page crashes the browser after a few seconds, and none of the Material UI 'accordion' components on the page display any results.

There are no errors in the console logs so I'm not sure what the issue is.

The source code can be found here: https://www.github.com/relativelyIntuitive/CarpeDiction

Comment: Use the Feedback Assistant to report this to Apple.

Comment: You need to tell more specific how you implement it, that would help us to assist you

Answer (score 0):

This does indeed crash Safari, but it is also a problem in Google Chrome and all browsers. If you open the site in Chrome and go to the developer tools and the network tab, watch what happens when you search. The app goes into an infinite loop endlessly calling your api. You should fix that because it could get expensive and/or crash your server.

The problem looks like it comes from the way you are using your useEffect functions, for example here:

https://github.com/relativelyIntuitive/CarpeDiction/blob/b213c8ed3d41fdf90172ec1e9f48ebda8fca6616/client/src/components/search/Comments.js

When you get the results back from the api you update the state with

```
setComments(resComments);
```

However, you also have comments as a dependency of the effect, which recalls the api every time you update comments, so it calls the function again and again and goes into an endless loop.

```
[query, comments]);
```

So you either need to remove that comments dependency, or add some logic to prevent the loop. Or use a library to help, such as react-async-hooks
https://github.com/slorber/react-async-hook